# PHP not working?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am fairly new to HTML and PHP, i know SQL and that's what i'm trying to use here (in PHP).

This is what i am using to create a simple connection to the SQL server, but this won't even work:

```
<html>
<h1>Test</h1>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username"; // Ofc with my SQL details.
$password = "password";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

But it get to this part `connect_error) {` and from there it just displays the code. Example:

[image]

^^ This is what comes up.

I think it has something to do with the PHP as it looks as if it's getting to the > and then thinking that's ending the PHP or something. Then again i could also be doing thing completely wrong - like i said, i'm new to HTML and PHP.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your assumption is right, PHP isn't being executed.

Comment: Are you using a server to execute this ? You can't just execute PHP code directly into the browser (you can't just drag & drop a file into your browser)

Comment: Make sure you're browsing `http://` not `file://`. Second, if that code is in a .html  file, make sure Apache executes it as .php as well.

Comment: Are you connect to the server ?

Comment: @AlexTartan I tried with http:// but it just says ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: @AlexandreBeaudet I'm using my browser, not drag & drop, but opening it normally. Is this  a problem?

Comment: Check my answer about Apache server, you need a server in order to use PHP ! It's not like javascript

Comment: I think that you should watch some tutorials in php first,  if you are having problem with the connection, then you may have problems with anything else in your way =/ such that displaying data from the database, or inserting things to the database

Answer (score 0):

> PHP files first need be processed in a web server before sending their output to the web browser. - See more at: http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/running-php-files/#sthash.rtr1MtAA.dpuf
>   To start using PHP, you can:
>
> ---
>
> 1. Find a web host with PHP and MySQL support
>
> OR/AND
>
> 2. Install a web server on your own PC, and then install PHP and MySQL

Since you're not talking about an apache server, I assume you're not using one !

In order to execute PHP, you need a server processing it. You can check this tutorial/course : http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_install.asp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your file is a PHP file. Check the file extension to be `.php`. Also note that the 4th parameter for MySQLi class is the database name that should be used. That being said, the `index.php` file should look like this:

```
<html>
<h1>Test</h1>
<?php
$host     = "localhost";
$username = "username"; // Ofc with my SQL details.
$password = "password";
$dbName   = "dbName";

$mysqli = new MySQLi($host, $username, $password, $dbName);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
<h2></h2>
```